# How to console.log from a custom server in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs app with a custom server to cache and fix urls.
Is there any way to console.log, or any other logging, to debug?
Next.js automatically clears the screen so any logs are erased.

I have found that there is a config option to stop the automatically clearing but couldn't figure out how to write it in the "next.config.js" file.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this whenever you call `const app = next({ dev });`

add preserve log like this:

`const app = next({ dev, preserveLog: true })`;.

Comment: Which version of next is this for? The option doesn't seem available in 8.1.0

Comment: try `const app = next({ dev, quiet: true });`

Comment: I tried it, but there are still all the "Compiling" and "Building page: " logs. Is there any way to completely stop these messages so I can log things in between compiling?